# Couchbase how to insert additional 'row' into a document using PHP

Tags: php, couchbase, nosql

I'm very new to Couchbase and NoSQL.

I'm trying to use Couchbase to store a long list of IDs that are generated throughout a user session.

Each ID is stored one at a time so I cannot create the document with multiple values. So, in PHP should this be done by creating a separate CB document for each ID or is there a way to insert a new row into this existing document? That's how I would do it in MySQL

I'm envisioning that I can first create the document using something like this:

```
$doc = array(
        'id' => '123'
   );
    $connection->set("s_591", json_encode($doc));
```

and then updating this same document by adding to the array that already exists in the document.

Comment: there is not nearly enough information here for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to store the IDs for each user session, then the most efficient way would be to use the [append](http://www.couchbase.com/autodocs/couchbase-php-client-1.2.2/classes/Couchbase.html#method_append) method of the Couchbase API. Append, as the name implies works on strings, not JSON documents, so you don't have to retrieve the object, update and store it back to Couchbase; you only send the string to be appended to the server and Couchbase adds it to the existing string atomically. To retrieve all the IDs, simply get the object (which is a string) and split it according to the delimiter.

So to store the ID "123" for user session "s_591":

```
$connection->append("s_591", "123" . ";");
```

To get back all the IDs:

```
$str = $connection->get("s_591");
$ids = explode(";", $str);
```